# Create Multiple QDialog with pass in valve

Tags: c++, qt, qdialog

I have a mainwindow it can do some search from MySQL,
eg. if I enter "abc", it will search all email with "abc" inside, 
then it will insert all result to a QTableWidget and show it, 
if i double click any of it,
it will create a QDialog by show() and pass that email I clicked by SIGNAL/SLOT,
the problem is, i want to create multiple QDialog if necessary. By double clicking another email, it should create another QDialog, but every time I open a new QDialog, 
all email I pass in will change to the last one I clicked, hope someone can teach me whats going on.

Here is my mainwindow double click function

```
void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_cellDoubleClicked(int row, int column)
{
    auto resule = ui->tableWidget->item(row, 1);
    Dialog* dialog = new Dialog(this);
    connect(this, SIGNAL(sendTargetEmail(QString)), dialog, SLOT(receiveTargetEmail(QString)));
    dialog->show();
    emit sendTargetEmail(resule->text());
}
```

Here is my QDialog function

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
QDialog(parent),
ui(new Ui::Dialog){


    ui->setupUi(this);

    label1 = new QLabel("Email:", this);
    label1->setGeometry(10, 30, 50, 20);

    emailLabel = new QLabel(this);
    emailLabel->setGeometry(60, 30, 160, 20);
}

void Dialog::receiveTargetEmail(QString email){
    m_email = email ;
    emailLabel->setText(m_email);
}
```

Comment: explain yourself better I do not understand. read [ask]

Comment: Why do you use signals and slots with sendTargetEmail? if you are happening synchronously.

Comment: @eyllanesc  Sorry for confuse, i wil try harder next time, about SIGNAL/SLOT beacuse i want to pass a specific email to dialog, i am planing do a full data display for that email in dialog.

Answer (score 0):

All your dialog instances will be affected by connected signal/slot, the slot will be called for all previously created dialogs as well.

... .. so all your dialogs labels text will change to latest `email` string!

If you want to keep the signal/slot connection for some reason, then don't use the slot to set the label text, you can set the text directly to the instance:

```
Dialog* dialog = new Dialog(this);
connect(this, SIGNAL(sendTargetEmail(QString)), dialog, SLOT(receiveTargetEmail(QString)));
dialog->emailLabel->setText(resule);
dialog->show();
emit sendTargetEmail(resule);
```

and remove this line from your slot:

```
emailLabel->setText(m_email);
```

---

### Edit

When you create a `Dialog` with `new`, you are dynamically creating that object. It will stay in memory unless it is explicitly destroyed or when its parent is destroyed. You are also making a connection to `receiveTargetEmail(QString)` every time you create an instance of `Dialog`. This connection is also permanent, unless that `QDialog` is destroyed.

Whenever you emit `sedTargetEmail()` the `receiveTargetEmail(QString)` slot of every instance of `Dialog` that you created earlier is being triggered. Instead of making a connection with SIGNAL/SLOT, you can directly call that function. This will make sure that only the last QDialog that you created is receiving the text.

```
void MainWindow::on_tableWidget_cellDoubleClicked(int row, int column)
{
    auto resule = ui->tableWidget->item(row, 1);
    Dialog* dialog = new Dialog(this);
    dialog->receiveTargetEmail(resule->text());
    dialog->show();
    emit sendTargetEmail(resule->text()); //you may have other things planned for the signal so you can leave it as is, depending on your design
}
```

Comment: Isn't he creating a new `Dialog` object every time he encounters the double click with `Dialog* dialog = new Dialog(this);`? Each `Dialog` seems to have its own `emailLabel = new QLabel(this);`. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Aditya Yes .. but when you change the text of that label .. which dialog is affected ?  ... all.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. It is because he makes a connection. So the slots from every `Dialog` is being executed! In that case, I think your answer can be worded better. It is correct though.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167372/discussion-between-aditya-and-mohammad-kanan).

Comment: thank you all, so I think the problem is I am using signal/slot, that will affect all created Dialog, since this is just testing the mechanism, my final plan is do a full custom data display of that email ,so i need the variable not change when i trigger other dialog.

Comment: actually after i post the question, i have a solution seems work fine, use constructor to pass the string in to dialog, if i trigger other dialog,the old one will not change.

Comment: @TANPAN Yes, you can add an argument in the constructor of `Dialog` to set the text instead of calling `receiveTargetEmail()` as well. And yes, I believe you are understanding the problem correctly, as explained in my edit.